# Sudoers File Corrupted in AWS Ubuntu Instance

Tags: sudo

Using AWS Instance , Ubuntu is the OS , Sudoers file is corrupted while trying to modify it and now it is not allowing me to do a su , even root access is denied.

pkexec is not installed on the AWS instance

Please let me know how to resolve this issue a step by step process would be appreciated.

Thanks
Aldrin

Answer (score 1):

You will need to spin up another AWS instance in the same AZ. Shutdown your problem instance, detach the root volume and attach the root volume to the new instance. Then you can edit the /mountpoint/etc/suduers file. Then detach the volume and reattach to your original instance. Shutdown and terminate the new instance.

This AWS document shows everything step by step.

[How to Recover an Unreachable Linux Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/how-to-recover-an-unreachable-linux-instance/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we've all done this once and learned that tough lesson. On a real system, I fixed it by booting a live OS off usb (or cdrom) and mounting the partition containing `sudoers`, then fixing the syntax error.   Not sure what the equivalent would be for an instance, perhaps DR/restore from a backup?

In the future, always run `visudo -c` to check `/etc/sudoers` for errors.  Or `visudo -c -f /path/to/my/sudoers`

Comment: This is an AWS Ubintu Instance.

Comment: Yes, so I wrote: maybe a rebuild and DR restore. Maybe others will know how to mount a partition of an instance.  Never tried.
My answer is more to make everyone aware of `visudo -c` to prevent this problem.

Comment: Hi any other way to resolve this issue , cannot work without sudo.